# Outlook Indexing Not Working Properly

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We've been running into issues with a lot of different users across our enterprise having issues with Outlook indexing emails for searches.

We've done all of the basic things to get this working, including:

- Making sure Outlook is selected for indexing
- Repairing .psf files
- Rebuilding the index

However, this hasn't resolved the issue for a number of users.

We've seen this issue occur on multiple OS's (Windows 7, 10, and Server 2008 R2) + multiple versions of Outlook (2013 and 2016) so it doesn't appear to be isolated to anything specific there.

Has anybody else seen similar issues? What sort of next steps should we be taking to getting Outlook searches/indexing to work properly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:** To provide more clarity - when users do searches, it will continually shows "Search results may be incomplete because items are still being indexed" but the indexing never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the users being affected by this were all using Outlook in Online mode vs. Cached mode so I checked Office 365's health and realized they're having a widespread outage across their cloud infrastructure causing this issue.

Reporting back here in case anybody else runs into this issue.

Putting their Outlook in cached mode fixed the issue while Microsoft fixes things on their end.

[image]